# When aligning the logo using float the header goes wonky HTML

Tags: html, css

So I'm extremely new to html and css and I want to create a website. But when I use float: left; to make my logo stay to the left, the header goes wonky.

https://jsfiddle.net/bm0dynw6/

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="logo" src="PolyNOTEMBLEM.png" width="330" height="82.5" />
  <button 
    id="Home"
    class="tablink" 
    onclick="window.location.href='[Redacted]'" 
  >
    Discord invite
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.header::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
```

or

```
.header {    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

and remove the `float:left` from logo

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS

```
.header {    
    display: flex;
    align-items:flex-start;
}
```